# Выборка many to many Yii2

Tags: yii2, activerecord, выборка

Делаю скриптик на Yii2.

Есть четыре таблицы (`files`, `permissions`, `banks`, `regions`).
Из таблицы `files` нужно выбрать только те записи, к которым у юзера есть доступ, и вывести в `GridView`.

Таблица `files`:

```
`files`.`id` - id файла
`files`.`bank_id` - к какому банку принадлежит файл
`files`.`region_id` - к какому региону принадлежит файл'
```

Таблица `permissions`:

```
`permissions`.`user_id` - кому предоставлять доступ
`permissions`.`bank` - к какому банку
`permissions`.`region` - к какому региону
`permissions`.`file` - к какому файлу
```

В общем, нужно сделать такую выборку в Yii2:

```
SELECT * FROM `files`
LEFT JOIN `permissions` ON('permissions`.`user_id` = _16_)
WHERE(
       (`permissions`.`file`=`files`.`id`)
     or
       (`permissions`.`bank` = `files`.`bank_id`)
     or
       (`permissions`.`region` = `files`.`region_id`)
)
```

Comment: В тексте вопроса сформулируйте сам вопрос.

Comment: А чем QueryBuilder не угодил для такого запроса? Все проще...

Answer (score 1):

к many-to-many вопрос не имеет никакого отношения вам нужно

```
$model = $connection->createCommand('SELECT * FROM `files`
LEFT JOIN `permissions` ON('permissions`.`user_id` = _16_)
   WHERE(
   (`permissions`.`file`=`files`.`id`)
 or
   (`permissions`.`bank` = `files`.`bank_id`)
 or
   (`permissions`.`region` = `files`.`region_id`)
   )');

$sql = $model->queryAll();
```

а про связь many-to-many для yii 2 можно прочитать [здесь](http://des1roer.blogspot.ru/2015/10/yii-2.html)